# Get resources from xml array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-mediaplayer, android-xml

I have an array in `xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="sounds_array">
        <item>R.raw.fart</item>
        <item>R.raw.beep33</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

I want to create a media player to play these sounds from my `raw` folder.

```
mSoundsArray = mContext.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.sounds_array);


mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, mSoundsArray.getResourceId(0, -1));
                mediaPlayer.start();
```

but istead of expected result I got an this error:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0xffffffff

any idea how can I get `resourceId` from this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i did the same sounds thing :

```
 Resources res = getResources();
        final TypedArray sounds = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.sounds_array);
        int[] resIds = new int[sounds.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length(); i++) {
            resIds[i] = sounds.getResourceId(i, -1);
        }
sounds.recycle();
```

Change :

```
 <array name="sounds_array">
    <item>R.raw.fart</item>
    <item>R.raw.beep33</item>
</array>
```

To

```
<string-array name="select_sounds">       
   <item>@raw/fart</item>
   <item>@raw/beep33</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I get two elements -1 in resIds. I should add .mp3 to every <item>R.raw.beep33</item> ?

Comment: I am not able to access items in raw folder using <item>@raw/fart</item>. any idea why is that?

Comment: @SAIR it wont autocomplete, but just type the full name and it should be fine